# Expo project can't be tracked by git inside github repository

Tags: git, react-native, github, expo

We are trying to initialize an expo project, however, our folder is recognized as a file by git and thus we are having commit errors. Our project structure is as follows

```
Root(recognized by git)>
  ExpoProject(tracked by git but wont be commited)>
  README.txt
```

Comment: Are you trying to run `git init` inside ExpoProject as a separate repo inside a repo, or just to add the file inside that folder to the parent repo?

Comment: Can you show us what commands you run exactly, and what error messages they produce? That would make it a lot easier to troubleshoot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having likely has to do with initializing your expo project inside of an existing git repository, which means that it is being tracked as a sub-repository (you don't want this). Try doing expo init 'project name' and then committing that to github.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rm -rf .git` inside the expo folder.

Expo adds a .git file to the project folder 'so you do not have to' and that's what causes the problem.